# How to view the content as a translation of Drupal 8 views

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a multi-language website where I have several views, the views publish the nodes in all languages. I want only the nodes of the language in which you are consulting the web to come out.
I have added two filters:

- Default translation -> true
- Translation language -> Interface text language selected for page

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a filter criteria "Default translation" -> true
2. In the section Language select "Interface text language selected for page"
   [image]